# autocomplete method in richfaces

Tags: richfaces

Can we call 2 autocomplete methods based on condition in a single rich:autocomplete tag?

I want to call 2 different methods in auto complete in my page based on an input value from a text box in my page

```
<rich:autocomplete
autocompleteMethod="#{}"
>

</rich:autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to merge the results of the two methods and I don't think there's a way to do that. But instead calling two methods, you can call one and that one can call the two.